# What is an owning contact?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

While going through *solidity* [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html) I came across a term 'the owning contract' which i didnt understand.

> A contract in the sense of Solidity is a collection of code (its functions) and data (its state) that resides at a specific address on the Ethereum blockchain. The line uint storedData; declares a state variable called storedData of type uint (unsigned integer of 256 bits). You can think of it as a single slot in a database that can be queried and altered by calling functions of the code that manages the database. In the case of Ethereum, this is always **the owning contract**. And in this case, the functions set and get can be used to modify or retrieve the value of the variable.

Comment: I believe "this" in that sentence refers to "the code that manages the database." In other words, the storage is part of (owned by) a smart contract, and the way to query and alter that storage is to interact with that smart contract.

Answer (score 0):

The owning contract means the contract that owns that block of storage on the Ethereum blockchain. The contract that "owns" this memory block is allowed to execute functions that read/write/delete/update the block's contents.

[See this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1701/what-does-the-keyword-memory-do-exactly) for a discussion of the two types of "memory/storage"